# usage of void** in c++ program

Tags: c++

I have to use `void**` in a program. I am writing the following code. please guide me where I am wrong.

```
struct kdnode
{
 kdnode* lch;
 int k;
 void **dataptr;
 kdnode* rch;
};
```

then I am assigning

```
kdnode rt;
rt.dataptr=new void*[k];
rt.dataptr[0]=new int;
```

there was also this dereferencing involved:

```
*(rt->dataptr[0])=n; //n is an initialized integer value.
```

basically I want to assign the elements of the array of void pointers to pointers of different datatypes. As the compiler is throwing error :

> `void*` is not a pointer-to object type

Please guide me what to do.

Comment: Why aren't you using standard-library containers like `std::vector` for this?

Comment: Maybe OP is interfacing with some C API?

Comment: Nothing illegal in the code you posted, except perhaps for the missing definition of `k`. Are you trying to dereference `rt.dataptr[0]` somewhere?

Comment: Compilation errors are printed, not thrown. Exceptions are thrown.

Comment: First thing that's wrong: using `void**` in C++.

Comment: Avoid void pointers. You lose type safety.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949761/c-error-void-is-not-a-pointer-to-object-type

Comment: The error would make sense if the code in your question isn't actually the code you're using. If there's a typo in the data types, and you've actually got a `void *` instead of `void **`. Can you please provide a complete minimal program that doesn't compile, that you think should?

Comment: Works for me here: http://ideone.com/LBZCuT

Comment: What compiler, what line number, and can you add to question the smallest possible compilation unit (file), without headers that will produce this error?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this error [only if I add something like](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a5a7bb75eb779e5)

```
*rt.dataptr[0] = 1;
```

With the addition, g++ complains:

```
main.cpp:13:14: error: ‘void*’ is not a pointer-to-object type
 *rt.dataptr[0] = 1;
```

You can't dereference a `void *`. Cast it back to the original type (`int *` in this case) if you want to dereference it.

Comment: FWIW, my guess for the typo was that the OP actually has `void *dataptr;` instead of `void **dataptr;`.