# Error error: ‘void*’ is not a pointer-to-object type

Tags: c++, linux, operating-system, pthreads

Hello Guys I am facing a slight issue in a code

This program is supposed to calculate 
 ( (a+b) x (c+d) ) / e

Create three threads, one for 
 Addition Only 
 Multiplication Only 
 Division

ONLY one thread should be created in main() 
Display the results in division thread. 
The int values(a, b, c, d, e) should be taken from the user in main and passed on the thread created in main. The other result of each step should be passed on the next step.

And this is the program that i wrote for above scenario

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void *Division(void *arg_div)
{
    int result = arg_div[0]/arg_div[1];
    cout << result ;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *Multiplication(void *arg_mul)
{
    int arg1[2];
    arg1[0]=arg_mul[0]*arg_mul[1];
    arg1[1]=arg_mul[2];
    pthread_t div;
    pthread_create(&div,NULL,Division,(void*)arg1);
    pthread_join(div,NULL);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *Addition(void *arg_add)
{
    int arg[3];
    arg[0]=arg_add[0]+arg_add[1];
    arg[1]=arg_add[2]+arg_add[3];
    arg[2]=arg_add[4];
    pthread_t ad;
    pthread_create(&ad,NULL,Multiplication,(void*)arg);
    pthread_join(ad,NULL);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    int values[5];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        cin >> values[i];
    }
    pthread_t pa;
    pthread_create(&pa,NULL,Addition,(void*)values);
    pthread_join(pa,NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void *Division(void *arg_div)` -> `void Division(void *arg_div)` for each of your functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++. Error: void is not a pointer-to-object type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949761/c-error-void-is-not-a-pointer-to-object-type)

Answer (score 3):

Why did you change the pointer type (C-style...) to `void*`? (trick question to make you walk on the proper path).

Just get the `int*` back, they are pointers that you can dereference. `void*` are pointers, but you can't get a `void` object and even less do operations on it.

```
int* args = static_cast<int*>(arg);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't dereference a `void*` - you need to cast the thread functions' parameters back to `int*`.

For example,

```
void *Division(void *arg_div)
{
    int* args = static_cast<int*>(arg_div);
    int result = args[0]/args[1];
...
```

Comment: Use C++ casts, not C-style.

Answer (score 0):

arithmetic on void pointer is not allowed, you need to convert void * to target type here i.e. int*

after converting to void* to int*, your Addition() looks like below, you have to make same changes to all function to make it work.

```
void *Addition(void *arg_add)
 {
   int *input = (int *)arg_add;
   int arg[3];
   arg[0]=input[0]+input[1];
   arg[1]=input[2]+input[3];
   arg[2]=input[4];
 }
```

Comment: Use C++ casts, not C-style.

Answer (score -1):

```
    void * Division(void * arg_div) {
        int * arg_div_int = (int * ) arg_div;
        int result = arg_div_int[0] / arg_div_int[1];
        ...
    }

    void * Multiplication(void * arg_mul) {

        int * arg_mul_int = (int * ) arg_mul;
        int arg1[2];
        arg1[0] = arg_mul_int[0] * arg_mul_int[1];
        arg1[1] = arg_mul_int[2];
        ...
    }

    void * Addition(void * arg_add) {

        int * arg_add_int = (int * ) arg_add;
        int arg[3];
        arg[0] = arg_add_int[0] + arg_add_int[1];
        arg[1] = arg_add_int[2] + arg_add_int[3];
        arg[2] = arg_add_int[4];
        ..
    }
```

Here is a fix to your problem. You have to convert the void* to a int* and then use the values in the int array.

Comment: Use C++ casts, not C-style.